# "Invalid operands to binary expression" error when comparing `char` with return value of `std::stack::pop()`

Tags: c++, stl, stack, comparison

I'm solving a LeetCode problem and I'm getting the following error:

```
> Line 15: Char 23: fatal error: invalid operands to binary expression ('char' and 'void')
            else if(c != st.pop())                  
1 error generated.
```

I set the stack to `char` type, but it seems to treat it as a `void` type? What could be going wrong?

**My code:**

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isValid(string s)
    {
        if(s.length() == 0)
            return true;

        stack<char> st;
        for(char &c : s) {           
            if(c == '(')
                st.push(')');
            else if(c == '[')
                st.push(']');
            else if(c == '{')
                st.push('}');
            else if(st.empty() || c != st.pop())
                return false;
        }
        return st.empty();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::stack::pop()` doesn't have a return value.

When you do `c != st.pop()`, compiler sees "*compare `char` value with `void` value*", what makes no sense.

Possible solution would be to first get the value from top to `temp` variable, then `pop()` and at least compare them:

```cpp
            else {
                if (st.empty()) 
                    return false;
                char temp = st.top();
                st.pop();
                if(c != temp)
                    return false;
            }
```

Comment: Thansk, but why I add the `st.empty()` and the result is the same.


```else if(st.empty() || c != st.pop())
                return false;```

Comment: @AnzerZ Because `st.pop()` is of `void` type. What adding `st.empty()` would change to it?